# Using a common project in several other projects in visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a `multi-solution project` on `VS 2013` in `C` (I must use `C` for this project). I implemented one `"Common"` project that I intended to use as a reference in another project. So I have one solution with a `common.h` and a matching `common.c` source in which I implemented all the common functions.

I now created a new `"Application"` project (inside the current one, so I now have 2 solutions) which does many things, and use the functions that are already implemented in the `common.c` file (that is in the `"Common"` solution). So I have a `app.h` file with a matching `app.c` source. I changed the settings so that the `"Application"` project will include the `"Common"` project.

However, when I run the `"Application"` solution (only it since the `"Common"` project is only used as a reference without a main function) I receive an error telling me that there is no reference to the functions in `common.h`.

I looked online for a solution and someone said that I should just copy the `common.c` to my `"Application"` project, however this is a very bad solution for me since I want to have multiple applications that all of them use the `"Common"` project.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Why did you pepper this post with code formatting around things that are not code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to copy any files to make this work. Right-click on your solution at the top of the Solution Explorer window. Choose Add -> Existing Project from the context menu. Find the project file for your "Common" project. It should show up in the list of projects for your solution.

Right-click your "Application" project in the solution explorer and choose "Properties" from the context menu. In the property pages window, go to "Common Properties". Click the "Add New Reference..." button. In the "Add Reference" window, go to the "Solution" tab, and then click the checkbox for your "Common" project. Click "Ok".

Now your "Application" project has a reference to your "Common" project. You can also open `common.c` and `common.h` from inside your new solution, and any changes will automatically be applied to all other solutions that reference it, because they are the original files and not mere copies.

The above method assumes that the output of your Common project is a DLL. Visual Studio (for whatever reason) won't automatically copy statically linked library (.lib) files. You can of course link against them, but adding a reference won't work. You will need to go to the properties page for your "Application" project, go to the linker -> input tab, and edit the Additional Dependencies line. You can also add the directory containing `common.h` to your Additional Include Directories under the C/C++ tab.

Either way, my opinion is that merely copying the files is a bad idea unless you're using modules in source control (e.g. Git modules or SVN externals) to manage dependencies.